# Set the last column as index in R

Tags: r, parquet, apache-arrow

I want to set the last column of my parquet file as the row name (i.e., index) of my dataframe.

My code raised `invalid 'row.names' length` error.

```
df <- read_parquet("file.parquet.gz")
rownames(df) <- df[,ncol(df)]
df[1:(length(df)-1)] <- NULL
```

Traceback:

```
Warning message:
“Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated.”
Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value): invalid 'row.names' length
Traceback:

1. `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = structure(list(`__index_level_0__` = c("TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A", ..., row.names = c(NA, -867L
 . ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
3. `row.names<-`(`*tmp*`, value = value)
4. `row.names<-.tbl_df`(`*tmp*`, value = value)
5. NextMethod()
6. `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value)
7. `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value)
8. stop("invalid 'row.names' length")
```

Comment: Don't use a tibble, change it to a normal `data.frame` first (with `df <- as.data.frame(df)`). Having said that, many operations (notably within the dplyr verbs) ignore or intentionally remove/do-not-retain row names, so this might be a losing battle. A common recommendation is that if you need that property attributed to a row, then keep it as a normal column.

Comment: To me this suggests two things: (1) whatever process is writing to the parquet file is writing a tibble, since the frame-dialect class is stored in the file and reconstituted when read, perhaps you can convince them (if row names are truly required) to lose the tibble dialect before writing, though this is really just working on the symptom; (2) regardless, while you're reading from a parquet file, and the parquet file does in fact contain that attribute buried with it, your question is actually not about parquet but about `tibble`s instead. `read_parquet` does not control that.

Comment: It is tibble because my file is in parquet format and I'm reading it from the `arrow` library, which reads the file as tibble.

Comment: Not true. `arrow::write_parquet(mtcars, "mt.pq"); class(arrow::read_parquet("mt.pq"))` returns `"data.frame"`, not `"tbl_df"` or any tibble-derived variant. It is tibble because whatever process _wrote_ that frame was working on it as a tibble. Contrast that with `arrow::write_parquet(tibble(mtcars), "mt.pq"); class(arrow::read_parquet("mt.pq"))` and you should see what I mean.

Comment: Back in `arrow_7.0.0`, one of the [NEWS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arrow/news/news.html) entries: *"`write_parquet()` no longer drops attributes for grouped data.frames"*. This means that attributes when-written will be attributes on read.

Comment: Regardless of _when_ it becomes a tibble, however, my two points remain: (1) row names are often discouraged for many reasons, _some_ of them relevant to whatever tools you are using (and some are often subjective/preference); and (2) if you really want that, use `as.data.frame(read_parquet(..))` and it will work (until something subsequently tibble-izes it).